# Do I lose features like autoprefixing by using the sx prop in MUI V5?

Tags: material-ui

I am new to MUI v5 and I have been using the `sx={}` prop a lot. But I was wondering if I was going to lose CSS preprocessing features by using it like this. I don't know how it works under the hood.

```
<AppBar 
        elevation={0}
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{
          borderTop: 0,
          backgroundColor: "white",
          color: "text.primary",
        }}
        position="static">
```

Comment: im having the same issue, css isnt being prefixed and this breaks my website for safari & firefox users